# rollapplyr moving window ADF

Tags: r, for-loop, while-loop, oracle-adf

So I want to do a rolling window that each time that it ends starts again with a bigger size window to calculate the ADF test. I'm thinking in a `rollapplyr()` in a `while` loop but what i have done is not working. Also I want that each time it rolls the ADF test creates a new Data.

This is my code:

```
C <- read.table("C:/Users/Alejandro/Documents/Universidad/Tesis/NASDAQ.csv", text = Lines, sep=",",dec=".",header=T)
head(C)

  Date Dividend
1    1 587.2105
2    2 564.3108
3    3 548.4872
4    4 521.1410
5    5 541.0921
6    6 563.5000

r11<-1
T<- 1336
rw<-9

for(i in 1:1326){
    while(r11<=T-rw+i){
    wi <- rollapplyr(C$Dividend, rw+i,function(u) adf.test(u)$statistic)
    r11<-r11+i
    }
   }
```

For some reason it stops at the first rolling of the ADF, so it just creates the data w1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of values returned by `adf.test` varies depending on the size of the rolling window in `rollapplyr` so you do need to accumulate the results in a list as **jeremycg** shows in his answer. However the `do.call` function may not work as shown.  I tried to replicate your problem using random dividend data with the same number of data points and window sizes and found that it runs for a very long time. To reduce running time while still giving results over a range of window sizes, I've modified the code to calculate ADF results at equi-spaced times in the dividend  series rather than at every time. Also the size of the rolling window is incremented by a value > 1 . The code now runs in a few seconds. The results contained in `wi` include both the sampling interval in the dividend series and the window sizes.  You can adjust `num_wind_sizes` and `num_samples` to get more dense sampling as needed.  Also, the end Date of the rolling window is shown for each value of the `ADF statistic` .

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the clarification.  I've simplified the code below in a couple of ways.  The increment in window size is fixed at 1.  Sample interval size can be specified directly; choosing `sample_interval` = 1 does the ADF calculation at every `Date` point which is what I understand you to be looking for.  Also, I've collected the calculated ADF statistics into a matrix `DF` which may be easier to work with for your purposes. The row indices of `DF` are the end `Dates` of the windows used in the ADF calculation.  The column indices of `DF` are the window sizes used in the ADF calculation.  For example, `DF[16,10]` is the ADF statistic for the series of 10 consecutive Dates ending on Date = 16; i.e. using window = 10.  The output of the example calculation below using only 20 Dates may help to clarify this a bit.

```
 library(zoo)
  library(tseries)
#  num_random <- 1336
  num_random <- 20
  set.seed(123)
  C <- data.frame(Date=1:num_random, Dividend=550 + 30*rnorm(num_random))  # generate randum sample data

# C <- read.table("C:/Users/Alejandro/Documents/Universidad/Tesis/NASDAQ.csv", text = Lines, sep=",",dec=".",header=T) 
  num_dividends <- nrow(C)
  head(C)

  rw<-9
  sample_interval <- 1  # sampling interval along dividend series; 
#                         sample_interval = 1 causes every point in dividend series to be used 
  wi <- list()
  DF <- matrix(0, nrow=num_dividends, ncol=num_dividends-1)
  for(i in 1:(num_dividends-rw-1) )  {
    wi <- c(wi,list(list(c(window_size=rw+i,sample_interval=sample_interval),
            DF=cbind(Date=seq(rw+i, num_dividends, by=sample_interval),
                    statistic=rollapplyr(C$Dividend, rw + i, function(u) adf.test(u)$statistic, by=sample_interval)))))
    DF[seq((rw+i),num_dividends,sample_interval), i+rw] <- wi[[i]]$DF[,"statistic"]
  }
 # row indices of DF are the end Date of the window used in the ADF calculation 
 # column indices of DF are the window sizes used in the ADF calculation
 # for example, DF[16,10] is the ADF statistic for Date = 16 using a window =10
  print(DF, digits=4)
```

Comment: Thanks @WaltS, I know that the running time is really long, but  I'm replicating the GSADF and it is this way. So I need that the code runs 1326 times from windows from 10 to 1326, and each time it runs it creates a new dataset; so at the end when `cbind` all the datasets I should have around 800.000 observations. I don't really understand your code so help me understand it, first what is the `sample_interval`, the function `floor` and what's an equi-space?. Also I am not sure if the second line creates a data each time it runs or it just `cbind` all the observations. Does it do what i need?

Comment: so the code works almost perfect, the only problem that I found is that the matrix `DF` is full of 0 but nothing i can't  deal with; I'm going to change the name of the question to make references to the GSADF so anyone looking how to do it in R can find it.

Comment: The matrix is basically lower triangular since the upper triangle would contain ADF statistics for window end times < window size which can't happen. The first rw columns of the matrix are zero since there are no window sizes < = rw.  Perhaps these zero entries would be better changed to NA.  These features should be evident in the DF matrix from example in the code.  With only 20 time points, the whole matrix may be easily viewed.

Comment: Yeah I get why they are zero and though of changing theme to NA so I could work with the matrix. Thanks agian

Comment: Hey, I know it has been some time but after doing this test for a few times I found that the code have a problem. It is that the starting point of the window is not fix and this creates serious problems to the test because basically almost all the statistics show explosive behavior. Really hope you can help because the only way I found to try to fix it was adding `partial=TRUE` with width `length=nrow(C)` which starts from the first observation (not what i need) and can't be used in the loop because the starting point can't be change.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your output with each iteration.

`wi` is simply overwritten each time. It sounds like you expect `wi` to be `w1`, `w2` etc, etc as `i` increments, but R does not work this way.

I have also corrected your `r11 <- r11 + i` to `+ 1`, as I guessed that's what you meant, change it back if it isn't.

The easiest way to fix your code, and make it run quickly is to make `wi` a list, and then rbind it at the end:

```
r11 <- 1
T <- 1336
rw <- 9
wi <- list()

for(i in 1:1326){
    while(r11 <= T - rw + i){
       wi[i] <- rollapplyr(C$Dividend, rw + i, function(u) adf.test(u)$statistic)
       r11 <- r11 + 1
    }
}
wi <- do.call(rbind, wi)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but for some reason is not working. I did the changes that you said and let it run for like 5 minutes, so it at least made like 3 rolling, but when using `View(w2)` it says that its not found so I guess it didn't run it. Also I don't know if the change of `r11<-r11+1` is correct I want that each time it rolls that r11 increase by one (I think is correct what you did but not completely sure). Last what does `do.call` does?

Comment: do View(wi), w2 will not exist. R does not increment any i in a variable name (otherwise you could never use anything with an i in it in a loop). wi holds all the data in a list, `do.call(rbind, wi)` turns the list into a data.frame. You will need to share some data for more trouble shooting.

Comment: it is not working, so I updated my code heading the data so everyone could see it. When I type `View(wi)` just shows me 1 value and if it run at least one time it should show 1326.